# Salvaging a PDF with highlights done in Android

Tags: recovery-mode, pdf

I was halfway highlighting a book using Acrobat Reader on an Android tablet when I dropped the tablet. The screen still 'sort of' works but is not usable as such (constant blinking etc). The tablet is still mountable on a computer.

Is there a way to salvage the pdf **including the highlights**?
(to be clear, i have the pdf saved elsewhere, but not the highlights)

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reader on the tablet saved the highlights on the fly. The reason i couldn't see those is because i was opening it using 'Document Viewer' on Linux Mint.
Using Adobe Acrobat on Windows shows the highlights as expected.